# Set a column equal to a range by incrementing values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set my column "C" equal to a range. I would like the range to be 0 to a MaxValue in increments of 0.1. So it would be like 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ...MaxValue. When I use this code it only gives me one value for the entire column. How would one go about this? Thanks in advance!

```
For p = 1 To MaxValue / 0.1
    For g = 0 To MaxValue
        ws1.Cells(p + 9, "C") = g + 0.1
    Next g
Next p
```

Comment: Running the debugger might reveal why this code is not working.  Your outer loop for `p` is controlling which cell is accessed.  Your inner loop for `g` is controlling the value that is output.  Unfortunately, the value for each `p` is going to be from the last iteration in the `g` loop since all the output goes to the single cell.  Also, depending on the value of `MaxValue`, it is possible you are getting non-integer row numbers which might cause problems.  Scott's answer is the cleanest solution for fixing this loop issue.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it without modifying your code too much.

```
g = 0
For p = 1 To MaxValue / 0.1

    ws1.Cells(p + 9, "C") = g
    g = g + 0.1

Next p
```

Comment: wont this set g to 0 each loop?

Comment: @ThatOneGuy - thanks. I placed it in wrong spot at last second. fixed

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple While loop to do what you are looking for. Just change the MaxValue to what you want

```
Sub test()
    Dim MaxValue As Double
    Dim p, counter As Double
    p = 0
    counter = 1
    MaxValue = 10

    While p < MaxValue
        Sheet1.Cells(counter, 3) = p
        p = p + 0.1
        counter = counter + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
Dim intOffsetCounter As Integer
Dim dblMaxValue As Double
Dim dblCurrentValue As Double

dblMaxValue = 10
dblCurrentValue = 0
intOffsetCounter = 1
Do Until dblCurrentValue = dblMaxValue
    If dblCurrentValue > dblMaxValue Then Exit Do
    Sheets(1).Cells(intOffsetCounter, 3).Value = dblCurrentValue
    dblCurrentValue = dblCurrentValue + 0.1
    intOffsetCounter = intOffsetCounter + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

You can change where the range starts by changing the intOffsetCounter to whatever row you want to start at.